# How to read file from remote ssh server in python program on local machine

Tags: python, ssh, file-read

I connected to SSH and can read "ls" of remote machine but I want to use cat or smth to read the auth.log file from the server. How can I do that? Down Below is my code please take a look.

```
import tkinter as tk
import paramiko
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os 
from subprocess import Popen

def setup_ssh_client():
print("establishing ssh connection....")
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
com="ls /var/log/"
client.connect(hostname="192.168.1.23", username="kmzpl", password="kilers1238!", port=22)
output=""
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(com)

print("ssh succuessful. Closing connection")
stdout=stdout.readlines()
client.close()
print("Connection closed")

print(stdout)
print(com)
for line in stdout:
 output=output+line
if output!="":
 print(output)
else:
 print("There was no output for this command")


 window = tk.Tk()
 connectButton = tk.Button(window, text="Connect", width=6, command=setup_ssh_client)
 connectButton.pack()
 window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have everything you need. Instead of running `ls`, run `cat`.

Comment: omg it was so simple? i am stupid i am so sorry